# WSO2 missing value when logging property

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm currently stuck with the following.

- Goal 1: get the URL in the log
- Goal 2  use it in the send mediator

Could you guys help me with both?

XML file:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <meta:MetaDataType xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1">
         <meta:Version>6.3</meta:Version>
         <meta:FixLevel>0.0</meta:FixLevel>
         <meta:Endpoint>http://555.555.555.55:8088/sal</meta:Endpoint>
      </meta:MetaDataType>
   </soap:Header>
```

The code in the proxy insequence so far:

```
 <property xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1" expression="$header//meta:MetaDataType/meta:Endpoint" name="URL" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1" expression="get-property('URL')" name="URL"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address format="soap11" uri="http://555.555.555.55:8088/sal"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
```

It prints the following:

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - URL =
```

Comment: do you want to get  <meta:Endpoint>http://555.555.555.55:8088/sal</meta:Endpoint> from the soap header

Comment: Yes, but it will not 'print' it in the current setting. Probably also too many namespace use

Comment: Nobody knows a way to print this? edit only "555.555.555.55:8088/sal" to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the given request and the XPath expression in EI 6.6.0 server and I could observe that the XPath is working as expected and logging the URL.

Request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <meta:MetaDataType xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1">
         <meta:Version>6.3</meta:Version>
         <meta:FixLevel>0.0</meta:FixLevel>
         <meta:Endpoint>http://555.555.555.55:8088/sal</meta:Endpoint>
      </meta:MetaDataType>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Proxy service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1"
                   expression="$header//meta:MetaDataType/meta:Endpoint"
                   name="URL"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property xmlns:meta="http://teswt.nl/xmlschemas/meeeeta/0.1"
                      expression="get-property('URL')"
                      name="URL"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Could you please enable the wire logs and check if the desired request is received by the service. You can also add a `<log level="full"/>` before extracting the URL to check the payload received.
In addition to that, what is the EI version that you are using

Comment: "Could you please enable the wire logs and check if the desired request is received by the service. You can also add a <log level="full"/> before extracting the URL to check the payload received." this literally did the trick to make me think of the solution. There was a payloadfactory that removed the meta:Endpoint already at the moment I declared the property. I moved it at the start of the proxy and now its working! Thanks for you efforts! Kudos on you ;)